# I need assistance with a query in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to do a count on the volumes in teredata on a table for a certain period but I keep on getting an error saying overflow occurred computing an expression.

```
SELECT CAST(timestamp_timestamp as Date) as DATEY, COUNT(transactionType)
FROM PRD_ACC_DIGIS_APP_PUB.SECURITY_CHECKS_RESULTS 
WHERE timestamp_timestamp BETWEEN '1700431200000' and 1700776800000
GROUP BY DATEY;
```

I am expecting to get the volumes.

Comment: that would imply there are more than 2^31 - 1 'SECURITY_CHECKS_RESULTS' for at least one day. I don't know your Domain but 2 billion per day seems high ?

Comment: Yes that is high

Comment: @MitchWheat am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Based on your BETWEEN clause it seems your timestamp_timestamp is epoch time in milliseconds? What is the data type for that column, BIGINT? You should not have quotes around the first value in BETWEEN, and you can't use CAST directly to extract the date. You could `CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_timestamp/1000) AS DATE)`

Comment: Not convinced this is truly a duplicate. You may want to edit the question to supply additional information like data types. But in any case, BETWEEN should never have one string bound and one numeric bound.